# LM7805 Voltage Drop too big

Tags: voltage, power, lm78xx

I setup the following circuit:

[image]

When I measure the voltage between GND and INPUT of the LM7805CV I have a voltage of 7.9V (around 8V as per power supply). But when I measure the output it is only 1.4V instead of expected 5V.

How is this possible? I don't see why the voltage drops so badly.

[image]

Comment: The schematic looks OK. Lets see a photo of your setup.

Comment: done... I measured at the voltage reg directly and I see the 7.9 volts on the input but only 1.4 at the output (so I assume it is the voltage regulator?!?)

Comment: Please disconnect everything else from the regulator output, leaving *only* that output capacitor. According to the photo, at the moment you are trying to power an unnamed (perhaps ATMega328?) MCU and who knows what else isn't visible off the right side of the photo :-) Then re-test. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure of the **exact** part number? I'm not finding any LM7805CV on the market. ST has an L7805CV, but no LM7805CV. (Best solution: give a link to the datasheet for the exact PN you're using)

Comment: The photo seems to have been taken at sunrise so much of it is in deep shadow. There are components connected that aren't shown on the schematic and we can't see what's connected behind the regulator. Nice, neat wiring though.

Comment: Does the LED glow?

Comment: Haha... the wiring took me longer than the rest. ;) When I disconnect everything else, the thing works again. LED is glowing and I measure 5V.

Comment: Strange... why is the voltage drop caused by the ATMEGA328P? Or do I miss anything here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have miswired the [ATmega328P](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega328P) MCU on the breadboard.

This is a crop from your photo, showing the problems:

[image: Original photo from question, cropped & annotated to show the wiring problems]

You have connected the Gnd rail to pin 20, which is the AVcc pin and should be connected to Vcc (through an optional filter). The MCU *might* have been damaged by this miswiring.

You have also connected the power & Gnd rails to pins 8 & 9 instead of the correct pins 7 & 8. Again, that *might* have caused internal damage to the MCU.

The miswiring (especially connecting AVcc pin 20 to Gnd) must be causing an excessive current inside the MCU, so that the regulator can only maintain that 1.4V which you measured on its output. This was confirmed since you updated that the correct 5V was measured on the regulator output, when the MCU was removed from the miswired breadboard.

Comment: Exactly what happened.... man............ 2 beer and uC working session is not a good idea

Comment: Maybe the PTC saved your beerbooboo